# How to detect whether the given point is in particular controls bound or not in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to detect whether the given point is in my controls area/bound or not.
example - Point(100, 100) I want to know whether it is on my button or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the point to the `Node` coordinate system and use [`Node.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#contains-javafx.geometry.Point2D-) to check, if the point is actually inside the `Node`:

The following example checks every 500 ms, if the screen coordinates (100, 100) are in the `Button`'s bounds

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button("Get (100, 100) in here");
    Point2D pt = new Point2D(100, 100);

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), evt ->
            System.out.println(
                   btn.contains(btn.screenToLocal(pt))
            )
    ));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 50);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: it works for buttons, but what about other controls? How to check weather the point is on particular menu, or on toolbar, or on tab controls header, etc.

Comment: @AmitaPatil:This uses only methods from the Node class and should be applicable to all kinds of Nodes.If you want to find the Node under a certain point,you'd need to do a search for the node through the scene graph.However in case you want to find the Node below the mouse cursor, use the [pickResult](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html#getPickResult--) You may need to go up in the node hierarchy to find a Node you're interested in.Tab headers don't provide a direct way to access them,looking up the appropriate selectors in the CSS reference may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `java.awt.Rectangle` variable marking the boundaries of your buttons and areas. Then use the method `Rectangle#contains` to test if the `Point` in question is within this area.

You may want to reference the Javadocs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html

Comment: can I apply same logic for tab header, menu bar, tool bar etc. ?

Comment: You may not be able to in this case, because these elements are outside of what can be captured by `Rectangle`. Worth trying, however. It depends on how you set up your menus.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using getGraphics() function

`Node n = tabShapes.getGraphic();

System.out.println("x = "+pt.x +" y = "+pt.y);

Point2D p = new Point2D(pt.x, pt.y);

boolean f = n.contains(n.screenToLocal(p));`